# cargar select type option a partir de una fecha input type date ajax c# json

Tags: c#, html5, ajax

Tengo un input de tipo date en HTML5 para seleccionar la fecha y a partir de la fecha llenar un select con opciones con el horario disponible de la base de datos para ese día. 
Para eso activo el evento onChange del input tipo date y utilizo ajax para llamar un método  [WebMethod] y json para llenar el select tipo option pero me arroja un error object object object

[image: al seleccionar fecha deberia cargar el horario disponible en el combobox tipo select option pero sale error object]

*Función ajax json*

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
            // armo el objeto que servira de parametro, para ello utilizo una libreria de JSON
            //este parametro mapeara con el definido en el web service
            var params = new Object();
            params.dia = $("#<%=fechacita.ClientID%>").val();
           params = JSON.stringify(params);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/citas5.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                data: params,
                //data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=fechacita.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            //$("#<%=hora1.ClientID%>").change(function () {
            //    alert("Ha seleccionado: " + $("#<%=hora1.ClientID%> :selected").text());
            //  });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            //quito los options que pudiera tener previamente el combo
            $("#<%=hora1.ClientID%>").html("");
            alert(response.d);

            //recorro cada item que devuelve el servicio web y lo añado como un opcion
            $.each(result.d, function () {

                $("#<%=hora1.ClientID%>").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.idhoras).text(this.horas))
            });
        }
```

*HTML5
CALENDARIO input tipo date*

```
<input id="fechacita" type="date" name="fechacita1"   onchange = "ShowCurrentTime()" autopostback="False" placeholder="Ingresa tu fecha" required="" runat="server"/>
combobox select tipo option
 <select id="hora1" type="option" value="1" name="hora"  runat="server" placeholder="Seleccione Tipo de Consulta" required=""/>

C#
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<CiudadEntity> GetCurrentTime(string dia)
        {

            var query = from item in GetPaises().AsEnumerable()
                        where Convert.ToString(item["time"]) != dia
                        select new CiudadEntity
                        {
                            idhoras = Convert.ToInt32(item["idtime"]),
                            horas = Convert.ToString(item["time"])
                            //descripcion = Convert.ToString(item["Ciudad"])
                        };

            return query.ToList<CiudadEntity>();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es como iteras los resultados, `this` no apunta a cada elemento de los resultados. usa los parametros de la funcion `$.each`

```
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        //quito los options que pudiera tener previamente el combo
        $("#<%=hora1.ClientID%>").html("");
        alert(response.d);

        //recorro cada item que devuelve el servicio web y lo añado como un opcion
        $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {

            $("#<%=hora1.ClientID%>").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", item.idhoras).text(item.horas))
        });
    }
```

Comment: realizo las modificaciones pero me sigue arrojando mismo mensaje object object object

Comment: pero el alert es correcto que te arroje eso. el select lo llena correcamente?

Comment: si el select es el que no llena correctamente

Comment: no mete ningun dato al select

Comment: Listo ya quedo gracias